# Picklist Value not Visible.

Tags: picklist

Added a PickList Value called "AAAAAAAAA" on Status field of Case Object.
Added this Value to all Recordtypes to avoid confusion.
But this value is not showing up while creating NEW record.
Kindly suggest.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your picklist dependent on another picklist? if so, you'll need to modify the allowed values on the dependent picklist as well to include the new value.

Comment: @DerekF, Standard Case Status picklist field cannot be dependent on other picklist. It should always be a controlling field

Comment: It is not a Dependant Picklist. Still there is this Problem. Other Picklist Fields are working good. Only the Status Picklist on Case has this Problem.

Comment: How many values does your picklist have?

Comment: one more Picklist field is acting weird too. We r thinking about raising a ticket to Salesforce.